# Event handle with dynamic id value

Tags: javascript

I have this update button in a table.

```
<button type="button" id="updateItem" onclick="changeLocation({{ id }})"
      class="btn btn-circle btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#update{{ id }}">
</button>
```

And I have to watch the on change event of a field inside the modal, so I have to have a dynamic ID for my event handler

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  var updateField = ""

  function changeLocation(id) {
    this.updateField = '#id_update-' + id
  }
  $(updateField).change(function(){
    alert("location changed")
  });
  
</script>
```

My problem is that the `updateField` value is not being fetched on the change event. It doesn't recognize the change in that input tag. Is there any way I can execute this?

Comment: There is a common misconception that in order to work with elements, they should have an `id`. Newer folks tend to give everything a static `id` and then, as their use cases grow more complex, they start giving their elements dynamic `id`s. After some time, maintaining code that relies on `id`s becomes very difficult to do. The code is brittle and hard to scale. The solution here is to avoid using `id`s in the first place. There are many other ways to refer to an element (`this`, `event.target`, `event.srcElement`, `.querySelectyor()`, and more). My advice is to stop using `id`s all together.

Comment: `{{ id }}`? is this angular

Comment: I'm in a Django template

Comment: The event is not magically going to rebind every time you change the variable. The event listener uses the variable at the moment in time. You probably want to look into event delegation.